# how to include/exclude directories with the same name

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project which contains a directory called node_modules but is not the node_modules created by npm. Since VSCode has a pre-configured exclusion for this folder (**/node_modules), I'm unable to search the other directory because this pattern matches all node_modules directories. How can I change the search.exclude to not search in the npm created directory (which is at the root) but search the one under a subdirectory? I've tried setting the exclude to:

```
"search.exclude": {
   "node_modules/*": true,
   "other/node_modules/*": false
}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable a pre defined pattern by putting this:

```
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": false,
    "node_modules": true
}
```

This will ignore a top level node_modules folder but not sub level ones.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize you have to disable. I thought you could just override the value completely.